# Using ZwNotifyChangeKey in Windows drivers

Tags: c++, windows, registry, driver

I want to create function that notifies me about registry key value changes (async). For this purpose I use [ZwNotifyChangeKey](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/ntifs/nf-ntifs-zwnotifychangekey).

```cpp
    // Create Notifier
    RtlInitUnicodeString(&KeyPath, L"\\Registry\\Machine\\SOFTWARE\\RegisteredApplications");
    InitializeObjectAttributes(&oa, &KeyPath, OBJ_CASE_INSENSITIVE, NULL, NULL);
    status = ZwOpenKeyEx(&hKey, KEY_NOTIFY, &oa, 0);

    if (NT_SUCCESS(status))
    {
        status = ZwNotifyChangeKey(hKey, hEventNotify, NULL, (PVOID)DelayedWorkQueue, 
            pio, REG_NOTIFY_CHANGE_LAST_SET, FALSE, NULL, 0, TRUE);

        ZwClose(hKey);
    }
```

```cpp
    // read notifications
    PVOID objects[] = { &evKill, &hEventNotify };

    while (TRUE)
    {
        status = KeWaitForMultipleObjects(RTL_NUMBER_OF(objects), 
            objects, WaitAny, Executive, KernelMode, FALSE, NULL, NULL);

        if (!NT_SUCCESS(status) || status == STATUS_WAIT_0)
            break;

        // Notifications are here
    }
```

But there're few gaps:

1. In documentation hEventNotify has type HANDLE instead of KEVENT
2. PIO_STATUS_BLOCK contains NTSTATUS and count of bytes in notification buffer, but WHERE IS that buffer? (*Buffer* field in kernel mode must be NULL)
3. How to process information from notification buffer?

Comment: if you use `Event` this of course must be handle to event object, use `NtCreateEvent` or `ZwCreateEvent`. but better instead event - use `ApcRoutine` - it must point to `WORK_QUEUE_ITEM` (allocated from non paged pool) - in this case you not need use dedicated thread. `IoStatusBlock` and `Buffer` not used when call from kernel. so simply pass 0 here. simply [example](https://pastebin.com/GuV6APsk)

Comment: `ApcRoutine` For a kernel-mode call, this parameter must be NULL. Inaccuracy in the documentation?

Comment: yes, very bad and wrong documentation. ApcRoutine can point to `WORK_QUEUE_ITEM`

Comment: Ok, Thanks)
However, I've done that using additional thread.

Comment: As I Understood, there's no way to determine the operation: rename value, delete value, create value. Just opaque change notification?

Comment: you can of course use and additional thread, but this is more bad solution compare use `WORK_QUEUE_ITEM`, *there's no way to determine the operation* unfortunately no, when previous mode is kernel. when user mode was previous - buffer filled with [`REG_NOTIFY_INFORMATION`](https://processhacker.sourceforge.io/doc/ntregapi_8h_source.html#l00196)  but because you use *Zw* api from kernel - you always got previous mode kernel, however i not understand why in this case buffer not filled

Comment: My aim is to track registry changes from user mode processes. So, in this case buffer will be filled with `REG_NOTIFY_INFORMATION`?

Comment: you not understand. if you call api from kernel - no info in buffer. you need call api from user mode for this

Comment: Oh, it's so bad (

Comment: yes, this is much more power - you in real-time get notifications about all registry operations and even can block or modify result

Comment: Ok, next time I will implement this using CmRegisterCallback